# Android GPS sensor don't enter onLocationChanged method

Tags: java, android, location

I am developing an android application for gathering data about the user location from the location sensor. Here is my code.

```
public class GPSService extends IntentService implements LocationListener {

public GPSService(String name) {
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public GPSService() {
    super("GPSService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private VSensorConfig config = null;

private static final String TAG = "AccelometerService";
public AndroidControllerListVSNew VSNewController;
public AbstractWrapper w;


private final Context mContext = null;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        Log.i("getLocation", "getLocation");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //TODO enja mishe parameter haro paas dad 
    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSService.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("onLocationChanged","onLocationChangedddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
    StreamElement streamElement = new StreamElement(w.getFieldList(),
            w.getFieldType(), new Serializable[] {location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()});

    ((AndroidAccelerometerWrapper) w).setTheLastStreamElement(streamElement);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    config = (VSensorConfig) b.get("config");


    Log.i("Service", config.getInputStreams().toString());

    for (InputStream inputStream : config.getInputStreams()) {
        for (StreamSource streamSource : inputStream.getSources()) {
            w = streamSource.getWrapper();
            Log.v(TAG, w.toString());

//          Activity activity = config.getController().getActivity();
//          mSensorManager = (SensorManager) activity
//                  .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
//          mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.Typ);
//          mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
//                  SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

//          while (w.isActive()) {
            while(true)
            {
                Log.i("accelometer ", "accelometer");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(w.getSamplingRate());
                    ((AndroidGPSWrapper) w).getLastKnownLocation();
                    Log.i("accelometer ", "accelometer");
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(e.getMessage(), e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

I have to build it as an intent service. 
The problem is that this code never enters the OnLocationChanged method. Can anyone help me with it?
I didn't move far from my first location yet. But it should at least print one location for me.

Thanks alot.

Comment: For the location updates to be called you'll have to move more than 10 meteres because you have `private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;` in your code.Please change that to 1 or so and check if it is called..

Comment: Also, since you have `private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;` location updates will be called in 1 minute..To check if it works change it to 1 or 2 seconds..

Comment: I changed them but it is still not working

Comment: is the gps getting fixed????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you probably aren't getting a GPS lock.  If you're inside at your computer testing, GPS generally doesn't work.  Is the GPS sign on your notification bar flashing?  If so, you're not locked and you aren't being called because GPS isn't working yet.

Secondly, an IntentService is a bad match for GPS.  You need a continual lock to the satellites to make GPS work.  An IntentService works briefly and then ends.  This would end the GPS connection.  It should be a normal service, not an intent service.

Third-  your code is terrible.  I've written a blog article [here](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/) about why that GPSTracker class is badly broken and should never be used.  I've posted better code here on SO before, but you can also find it at that link.  It won't solve the problem of not getting satellite lock, but it will fix other problems in that code.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. I am running the program on samsung galaxy 2 device and the GPS is on in the notification. So how can I get the lock?

Comment: And about the IntentService, I am modifying a code which keeps track for several sensors. and all of them are built with IntentService. Is it OK to have both service and IntentService together? I have infinite while in my intentService. So will it end?